# Alternate solution for CSS zoom

Tags: html, css, transform

I use CSS `zoom` to shrink the preview of a big `div`.

```
<div id="layoutEditCanvas" style="width:1920px;height:1080px;background:url('{{layout.backgroundImage}}')">
</div>
```

`zoom` set like this:

```
zoom:0.5;
```

Now, FF doesn't support `zoom` so I have to use

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.5);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

My problem is that while Chrome takes the CSS `zoom` and shrinks my `div` to 960 x 540, FF leaves the `div` with its original size and only scales its contents, leaving me with a huge empty space around the shrunk content.

Is there a parameter to have the (scale) transform to behave like `zoom`?

Comment: As fas as I know, and I would say that (sadly), there is no way. And that is not the FF fault, but it's what the w3c specs say.

Comment: What I did is that I used `transform:scale` and set a negative margin to get rid of the empty space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it's possible to avoid this effect by setting fixed height/width and overflow:hidden on the element wrapping the "transform scale"'d element, thus hiding that overflow created by the scaling.